# Method is looping by itself without being called in a loop in winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a windows form application in which there is a method which dynamically creates controls on a panel but don't know how the method is getting called again and again without being called from a loop this cause controls on panel recreated everytime and panel flicker like nuts

I am unable to find the reason for that any help willbe higly appreciated

Here is the code from which Default controls are loaded

```
internal void LoadDefaultControl()
{

        switch ((ProductType)_tillContext.Till.DefaultProductType)
        {
            case ProductType.Gift_Voucher:
                LoadGiftVouchersControl();

                break;
            case ProductType.Merchandise:
                LoadMerchandiseControl();
                break;
            case ProductType.Service:
                LoadServicesControl();
                break;
            default:
                LoadAdmissionsControl();
                break;
        }

}
```

Below method is calling the above method

```
private void RenewMembership(Domain.Members.Member member, MembershipAdmissionValidityHelper.MembershipAdmissionValidity validity)
    {
        var wizard =
            new PurchaseWizard(control => new MembershipRenewalProcessController(member, validity,
                                            new MembershipRenewalInteractionController(control, _tillContext),
                                        _tillContext))
            {
                Size = pnlWorkArea.Size
            };

        wizard.OnCancelled += LoadDefaultControl;
        wizard.OnPurchaseCreated += purchase =>
        {
            AddItemToBasket(purchase);
            LoadDefaultControl();
        };

        ClearControls();
        pnlWorkArea.Controls.Add(wizard);
    }
```

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: Hi guys I have updated my question please help

Comment: also post the code from where u call this method

Comment: If you are in visual studio, press `ctrl+shift+f` and search for `LoadDefaultControl` to see from where this method is getting called.

Comment: You need to post the code that calls the LoadDefaultControl() method and the code for LoadGiftVouchersControl() and LoadMerchandiseControl() and LoadServicesControl() and LoadAdmissionsControl()

Comment: You should talk a little about other methods: `LoadGiftVouchersControl()`, `LoadMerchandiseControl()`, ...

Comment: The other methods like LoadGiftVouchersControl() are just creating some dynamic controls on a panel the main culprit is Loaddefaultcontrol which is called again and again

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint at the beginning of `LoadDefaultControl` and running your program under the debugger? You'll then be able to inspect the call stack each time `LoadDefaultControl` is called.

Comment: @c45207 The call stack shows me that call is correct to the method but the method itself is called again and again not sure what is causing this wierd behaviour

Comment: Post the code from where u call this method !

Comment: difficult to say from it, you need to set a breakpoint and see how many times its been called and how.

Comment: @tariq I think I found the suspect its the handler attachment don't know how but it is storing the invocation count each time the method is attached to it and then calling the method on the basis of that invocation count

Guys please let me know if I missed something

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are declaring `wizard` inside `RenewMembership` the fact that it has a handler subscribed to the `OnCancelled` event means that it's never being garbage collected.

Either create the wizard once and once only, adding the event handler then or add the following line to remove the handler:

```
wizard.OnCancelled -= LoadDefaultControl;
```

Now this will need to be done *after* the event fires so is best done in the event handler itself. That means that you need some way of passing the reference to `wizard` into the handler.

Given that this could get messy very quickly it might be simpler to go with making `wizard` a private property of the class and only create it once and only add the handler once.